# How to expose a Flow in a Community using the Napili template?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, napili

In the pre-community-templates era, we could expose a Flow to external users using the `<flow:interview>` component in a Visualforce page.

(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_distribute_external.htm)

The Community Builder does not let you add Visualforce pages directly, so I  tried to add the Visualforce page, containing the `<flow:interview>` component, to a Lightning Component as an iframe (bad idea?).

It kind of works with a very simple Flow, but soon I hit the "Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded" error for the Visualforce page.

Any ideas on how to successfully expose a Flow in a Community using the Napili template (preferably using the Lightning Runtime for Flows)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a little late, but you can do it by creating a tab that launches an external URL and put in the URL for the flow in there. It'll open the flow in a new tab. And as long as you have the lightning skin enabled, it'll be the pretty version.